# greater than symbol works but less than not in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, soapui, ibm-datapower

I have Datapower http based MPG service. I am getting response soap message from backend which has Size element values Ex:

```
<Size><10000</Size>
<Size>10000></Size>
```

It is showing correctly as it is in datapower probe. but when it comes to soapUI lessthan symbol not showing correctly.Showing like below:

```
<Size>&lt;10000</Size>
<Size>10000></Size>
```

How to get '<' less than symbol correctly?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The follow symbols in a `XML`: `<`, `>`, `"`,`'`,`&` could be replaced by `&lt;`,`&gt;`,`&quot;`,`&apos;`,`&amp;` respectively. In the `XML` text to avoid errors it's recommended to replace all, but only `<` and `&` must be replaced all the times (as `@michael.hor257k` comments). Alternatively to avoid the replacement it's possible [to use `CDATA`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect)).

Probably Datapower "prettify" the response before it shows you (here I'm only guessing since I don't know Datapower).

SOAPUI doesn't perform any transformation in your response and it is showing the response like it is, this is why you see `&lt;` character; due your web server replace `<` to avoid generate a invalid `XML` response.

[Here you can see a good response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/1218618) explaining the general rules for this characters in `XML` depends on where they are.

Comment: Actually only `<` and `&` must be escaped at all times. That's why OP sees `>` as before.

Comment: @michael.hor257k right `:)`, thanks!. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Less than symbol` is escape character in XSLT. So you can use `&#x003C;` instead of &lt;